# WSO2is authentication SOAP using digest password

Tags: wso2, md5, digest, wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2is v. 5.0.0

I need to authenticate the users via SOAP. The problem is that my application can't send a clear password. My application can send only a digest MD5 password to WSO2is.

Can I make some configuration on WSO2is to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you read on http://wso2.com/library/240/?

Answer (score 0):

All credentials (username, password) are passed to the userstore manager(s) invoking the "authenticate" method. If you create a custom userstore manager (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager) which would authenticate the users based on the hash (md5), then the hash will be considered as the user password (however, it's not very common, usually the user password is passed to the identity server to authenticate regardless the user storage).